# "que l'on peut faire"

Tags: grammaire

Dans la phrase:

> La première remarque importante que **l'** on peut faire

Pourquoi met-on ce "**l'**" avant le pronom? Est-ce que c'est un usage similaire à l'explétif "ne"?

Comment: tl;dr So that it sounds better. It serves no other purpose.

Comment: The fact it sounds better is a reason why this article is often kept but it also used to serve a grammatical purpose: *La première remarque importante que **l'homme** peut faire*.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai vu l'article en question. Mais je pense qu'il faut une meilleure source que deux phrases sur un blog anonyme.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi ?? http://www.academie-francaise.fr/pauvre

Comment: @jlliagre L'article que j'ai vu (dans le lien que j'ai donné) venait de druide.com, qui ne donne aucune source. Je ne connaissais pas cet article, merci.

Answer (score 3):

"Que l'on peut faire" par exemple dans l'expressions "ce que l'on peut faire" devient, si l'on ôte ce "l'" deviendra "Ce qu'on peut faire" mais phonétiquement est semblable à "Ce con peut faire" et là on entre dans la vulgarité.
À éviter l'emploi de "Qu'on" et remplacer par "Que l'on"

Answer (score 0):

Ce l' (on dit l élidé) ne joue d'autre rôle qu'un rôle phonétique. Je trouve que c'est plus habituel dans un registre plus soutenu.

Voir:

http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_44_on_lon.shtml

[https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/on-vs-lon/](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-use-lon-on-in-french-4083659)